# List of dict to aggregated list of dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am looking for a pythonic/elegant way to transform my list of dict (e.g. `LD`) into a aggregated list of dict (e.g. `DD`).  The dict in `LD` have `id`, `result`, and `count` as keys, and there can be multiple dict's with the same `id` with different `result`s.  The resulting dict `DD` should aggregate the `id`'s together and display all the `result`s  together (in `results`).

Here is an example:

```
LD = [
    {'id':1, 'result': 'passed', 'count': 10},
    {'id':1, 'result': 'failed', 'count': 20},
    {'id':2, 'result': 'failed', 'count': 100}
]
```

Here is the output I want

```
DD = [
    {'id':1, 'results': {'passed': 10, 'failed': 20}},
    {'id':2, 'results': {'passed': 10}}
]
```

I could create a for loop and a output dict to process each items in `LD`, but am wondering if this can be achieved in a one-liner using things like `zip`, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your dict of dict looks like just another list of dicts to me

Comment: looks like you want to aggregate the elements with similar id's. it doesn't look like a nested dict.

Comment: My bad -- you are correct!  I fixed the wording.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
LD = [
{'id':1, 'result': 'passed', 'count': 10},
{'id':1, 'result': 'failed', 'count': 20},
{'id':2, 'result': 'failed', 'count': 100}
]
new_result = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(LD, key=lambda x:x['id']), key=lambda x:x['id'])]
last_result = [{**{'id':a}, **{'results':{i['result']:i['count'] for i in b}}} for a, b in new_result]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'results': {'failed': 20, 'passed': 10}}, {'id': 2, 'results': {'failed': 100}}]
```

Edit: Python2 version:

```
new_result = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(LD, key=lambda x:x['id']), key=lambda x:x['id'])]
last_result = [dict([('id', a)]+[('results', {i['result']:i['count'] for i in b})]) for a, b in new_result]
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'results': {'failed': 20, 'passed': 10}}, {'id': 2, 'results': {'failed': 100}}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Ajax1234.  What does the `**` do?  Is this supported in python 2.7?  I am getting a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at the first `**`.

Comment: @MaggieYing Glad to help! `**` is for dictionary unpacking, and while it can be used for unpacking in object parameters in Python2, only in Python3 can it be used in other dictionaries. Please see my recent edit, as I wrote a solution compatible with Python 2.

Comment: This relies on the input data being pre-sorted by ids.  You should at least mention that, since OP didn't specify whether data was sorted.

Comment: Now it's O(n log n).  This should be solved in O(n).    –1

Comment: This solution seems to fail for repeated dictionaries in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution via `collections.defaultdict` which does not rely on sorting + groupby.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for i in LD:
    d[i['id']][i['result']] += i['count']

res = [{'id': k, 'result': dict(v)} for k, v in d.items()]

# [{'id': 1, 'result': {'failed': 20, 'passed': 10}},
#  {'id': 2, 'result': {'failed': 100}}]
```

Comment: This is not a one-liner as the OP wished.

Comment: So?  Just because you can one-liner, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I'm more concerned about Ajax's solution not working for repeated dictionaries, which might be fine - but should be noted.

Comment: @jpp Can you define "repeated dictionaries"?

Comment: `[{'id':1, 'result': 'passed', 'count': 10}, {'id':1, 'result': 'passed', 'count': 10}]`